# Putting pictures on website using lightbox

Tags: php, performance, lightbox

I'm in the process of making a website for a school group and the website will have a lot of pictures of its activities. I'm using lightbox so the pictures will display as a slideshow and I changed the dimension of the pictures so the "current" picture on slideshow isn't as big as the original. I still find about 5 seconds delay from opening the picture or going to the next picture. I'm wondering if there's a way to achieve a faster load time or even another method I didn't consider.

I'm using xhtml, css, and php for my site.

Comment: How did you change the dimension? Did you actually resize the image, ordid you just put a width and a height attribute in your HTML/CSS?

Comment: You should preload images when page loads.

Comment: I just put a width and height attribute, so it's better to actually resize it? That seems like it'll take some time to resize each picture manually 

And I'm not sure what you mean by preload

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for answering, but I can't write comment now...

I'm doing it other way, after upload, I resampled picture to big picture and thumbnail.

Ofcourse you can resampled picture everytime, but this is propably reason, why you have to wait so long, and it is lots of work for server, if you have many visitors in one moment.

So for me is best way to said, that big image is 640x480 max, and then save picture after upload to this size, ofcourse resampled by the same ratio.

**Edit:** From your post, I can't know if you resizing/resampling image, and where, in HTML by setting height and width or in PHP and how often.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Your english is a little hard to understand. I'm guessing you mean you set your pictures to 640x480 size after you save them. I didn't do that so I'll try, but I'm still confused of what you mean by resampling.

Comment: Yes, you understood it correctly. When user upload picture, I resample it, and save only smaller picture, ofcourse, you can save even original picture.
Resampling is better method for resizing picture. Better than words is example: [Look here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/64c05q8bh65rzsy/YV8O1CWiny) in left-bottom corner is name of picture (resized/resampled)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a picture on the server, and its size is 8000x6000. its size could be something like 10 MB.

Now let's say you want to display this image in a web page and do it like this:

```
<img src="largeImage.jpg" width="800" height="600"/>
```

The browser will download the large image (10 MB), which takes a whole lot of time, and will then resize it to 800x600 in memory to display it on the web page (this consumes memory and CPU time). Total time: 25 seconds.

Now suppose you resize this image to 800x600 and put this resized image on the server. You then display the image with

```
<img src="smallImage.jpg" width="800" height="600"/>
```

The small image will look identical to the user visiting your web page, but the browser will only have to download a small image, which will be something like 100 KB large (100 times less than the large image). The time taken to download the image will be divided by 100 as well (0.25 seconds), and the browser won't have to load and resize a huge image in memory (less memory, less CPU time). Your image will be visible almost instantly.

There are many tools (I use Irfanview myself) which are able to take a large collection of images and resize them all at once. You should do that.

Comment: Do all browsers resize pictures to 800x600?

Comment: They do if you tell them to do it with `width="800" height="600"`